# Create context menu using JQuery with HTML 5 Canvas

Tags: jquery, html, canvas

I try to develop HTML 5 Canvas has context menu. When click for every image in Canvas, it will show context menu for each image. At there, I has only one canvas

```
<canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas>
```

It will show all image when I draw. I try some jquery library context menu, It only support in case have more canvas (because it using `class` or `id` element for detect HTML element).

Now I want using only 1 canvas, I had been detected click for each image in canvas but I don't know how to create context menu. Can you suggest me using jquery library or give me example in my case.

Thanks.

Comment: One idea is to use an unordered list as a context menu and listen for clicks on it's list items. You can rebuild the UL's list items based on which canvas image was clicked. You can set the UL `position:absolute` to control its position over then canvas (or push it off-screen when not needed).

Comment: Thanks, I had been try show/hide context menu when click for item in canvas, it's OK. But I think it's not good.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**One idea is to create your own custom context menu using an unordered list.**

- Override the default context menu by listening for `contextmenu` events on the canvas.

  ```
  canvas.addEventListener('contextmenu', handleContextMenu, false);
  ```
- When the context mouse button is clicked inside a particular image drawn on your canvas you can rebuild the UL with list items individualized for the image that was clicked.
- Set the UL's `position:absolute`, `left`, `top` to position your context menu over the mouse position on the canvas.
- You can hide the UL when its not needed.
- Listen for click events on the UL's list items to respond to a users context menu selection.

**Example code and a Demo:**

```js
var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
var cw=canvas.width;
var ch=canvas.height;
function reOffset(){
  var BB=canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
  offsetX=BB.left;
  offsetY=BB.top;        
}
var offsetX,offsetY;
reOffset();
window.onscroll=function(e){ reOffset(); }
window.onresize=function(e){ reOffset(); }

var $menu=$('#contextMenu');

var rects=[];
rects.push({x:50,y:50,width:50,height:50,color:"red",contextMenu:['One red','Two red']});
rects.push({x:150,y:100,width:75,height:75,color:"blue",contextMenu:['One blue','Two blue']});

ctx.clearRect(0,0,cw,ch);
for(var i=0;i<rects.length;i++){
  var rect=rects[i];
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.fillStyle=rect.color;
  ctx.rect(rect.x,rect.y,rect.width,rect.height);
  ctx.fill();
}

$('#contextMenu').on('click','li',function(e){
  // hide the context menu
  showContextMenu();
  alert('Context selection: '+$(this).text());
});

// hide the context menu
showContextMenu();

canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', handleMouseDown, false);  
canvas.addEventListener('contextmenu', handleContextMenu, false);  

function handleMouseDown(e){
  // hide the context menu
  showContextMenu();
}

function handleContextMenu(e){
  // tell the browser we're handling this event
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();

  // get mouse position relative to the canvas
  var x=parseInt(e.clientX-offsetX);
  var y=parseInt(e.clientY-offsetY);

  // hide the context menu
  showContextMenu();

  // check each rect for hits
  for(var i=0;i<rects.length;i++){
    var rect=rects[i];
    var rectRight=rect.x+rect.width;
    var rectBottom=rect.y+rect.height;

    // check each rect for hits
    if(x>=rect.x && x<=rectRight && y>=rect.y && y<=rectBottom  ){
      showContextMenu(rect,x,y);
    }
  }
  return(false);
}

function showContextMenu(r,x,y){
  if(!r){$menu.hide(); return;}
  $menu.show();
  var m=r.contextMenu;
  $menu.empty();
  $menu.css({left:x,top:y});
  for(var i=0;i<m.length;i++){
    $('<li>', { text:m[i], 'data-fn':i, }).appendTo($menu[0]);
  }
}
```

```css
body{ background-color: ivory; padding:0; }
#canvas{border:1px solid red;}
#canvasContainer{position:relative;}
#canvas,#contextMenu{position:absolute;}
#contextMenu{
  border:1px solid green;
  background:white;
  list-style:none;
  padding:3px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h4>Right click on rect for context menu.</h4>
<div id=canvasContainer>
  <canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas>
  <ul id=contextMenu><li>Test</li></ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks @markE. I had been try and it's ok. Thanks for support.

Comment: Like the way you adjust for window scroll and resize. I opted to collect all the hits and if there were multiple I selected one to context.