# How to display a menu on user click in canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

I'm a begginer with canvas element but my research on google didn't go well... So, I have my canvas element and I draw a lot of rectangles in my canvas.

Currently, when I click in my shape I'm able to display an alert message like 'You clicked on the rectangle 54'. But I don't want to display an alert box. I want to display a menu with some options like 'Delete' or 'More details'...

I found a tons of article about a menu on javascript on html element but nothing about canvas... I Found only something working with Firefox...

Is there a way to do that?

At the moment I think, I will draw a new rectangle displaying the options, but it looks like a bit dirty and i'm affraid about conflict event...

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What is this "menu" ment to do? I.E. does it show new menus? does it delete existing menus? It is like a file system where you can keep going deeper and deeper? Have you got some example code is a jsfiddle we can take a look at?

Comment: Depending on where the user clicks, a menu might easily need to extend off the canvas area so using the canvas itself to display the menu is a bit limiting. A good idea is to hit-test your shapes and on-click you can show a hidden div containing whatever html elements you want on your menu.

Comment: It's standard menu like you can see here : https://jqueryui.com/menu/ . Just I don't understand how to enable it on canvas' rectangle. A dropdown could be fine but how to display it when I click on my rectangle?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31601393/create-context-menu-using-jquery-with-html-5-canvas/31603565#31603565