# Context menu on canvas

Tags: html, canvas, contextmenu, paperjs

I'm trying to use [jQuery context menu](https://github.com/swisnl/jQuery-contextMenu)  to add a context menu on a specific element drawin in a html5 canvas, but I have no idea how i could bind it to that. Any tips?

Answer (score 2):

**Shapes drawn on html5 Canvas cannot be referenced**

Any specific shape/path you've drawn on canvas is not remembered -- the shapes are just pixels on the canvas. So you can't bind your context menu to the un-referenceable shape.

**So...You must manually find your shapes**

As a starting point, you need to find your shape in the "sea of pixels".

**Finding circular & rectangular shapes with Math**

If the shape is rectangular or circular, you can mathematically find if the mouse-click is inside the shape using basic math.

```
// test if the mouse is inside a circle
// Given the circle's centerpoint and its radius
var dx = mouseX-circleCenterX;
var dy = mouseY-circleCenterY;
var mouseIsInCircle = (dx*dx+dy*dy)<(circleRadius*circleRadius);

// test if the mouse is inside a rectangle
// Given the rectangle's x,y,width & height
var mouseIsInRect=(
    mouseX>=rect1.x &&
    mouseX<=rect1.x+rect1.width &&
    mouseY>=rect1.y &&
    mouseY<=rect1.y+rect1.height);
```

**Finding more complex paths with `context.isPointInPath`**

One way to reference paths on the canvas is to put the commands that created the path in an object. When you need to hit-test that path to see if the context menu should deploy, you can redefine the path and use [`context.isPointInPath`](http://www.rgraph.net/blog/2013/february/an-example-of-the-html5-canvas-ispointinpath-function.html). This previous Stackoverflow [Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36725832/mouse-hover-canvas-shape/36731125#36731125) shows how to use `isPointInPath` to test if the mouse is inside your complex path.

**A better way with Path2D**

[`Path2D`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Path2D/Path2D) is built into most modern browsers (but not IE) and it allows you to save a reference to your complex path. Then you can have `context.isPointInPath` use that Path2D definition to [hit-test your Path2D](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/isPointInPath).

**The context menu itself**

Here is a previous Stackoverflow [Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31601393/create-context-menu-using-jquery-with-html-5-canvas/31603565#31603565) that shows how to create a custom context menu.

If you want to use the jQuery context menu you will need to dynamically create  on-demand menus and configure the menu to show at the desired [x,y] on the canvas. [Some assembly is required](http://swisnl.github.io/jQuery-contextMenu/index.html)